# Azure Mobile Service .NET Backend HttpResponseMessage return null Content

Tags: c#, azure

I had this function in the web api of the mobile service declared

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    EasyParkContext context = new EasyParkContext();
    User user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == loginRequest.UserName);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(loginRequest.Password, user.Password))
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, user.Id));
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginRequest.UserName));
            LoginResult loginResult = new EasyParkLoginProvider(handler).CreateLoginResult(claimsIdentity, Services.Settings.MasterKey);
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, loginResult);
        }
    }
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password");
}
```

And this function declared in my client

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string userName, string password)
{
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest() { UserName = userName, Password = password };
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage loginResult = await _service.InvokeApiAsync<LoginRequest, HttpResponseMessage>("EasyParkLogin", loginRequest);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(loginResult.Content.ToString());
        _service.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(json["user"]["userId"].ToString().Replace("EasyPark:", ""))
        {
            MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = json["authenticationToken"].ToString()
        };
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works at the mobile service page, but is returning null during my client code, sorry I can't attached the image due to my reputation...

Comment: which is null - `json` or `loginResult`, or `loginResult.Content` - depending on which, the cause could be different. Also it might be good to see the code of `_service.InvokeApiAsync`

Comment: @StephenByrne
loginResult.Content is null, the _service is simply initializing the mobile service connection. if you do wish to take a look on the image, you may check out [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/12209e2b-b49a-4ae6-bff5-277adef4d7b7/azure-mobile-service-net-backend-httpresponsemessage-return-null-content?forum=azuremobile)

Comment: Glad to see you have gotten it sorted in the meantime :)

Comment: @StephenByrne hahaha, still thanks for stopping by! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public async Task<bool> Login(string userName, string password)
{
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest() { UserName = userName, Password = password };
    try
    {
        var loginResult = await _service.InvokeApiAsync("EasyParkLogin", JToken.FromObject(loginRequest));
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(loginResult.ToString());
        _service.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(json["user"]["userId"].ToString().Replace("EasyPark:", ""))
        {
            MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = json["authenticationToken"].ToString()
        };
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

by changing the from the code:

```
HttpResponseMessage loginResult = await _service.InvokeApiAsync<LoginRequest, HttpResponseMessage>("EasyParkLogin", loginRequest);
JObject json = JObject.Parse(loginResult.Content.ToString());
```

to

```
var loginResult = await _service.InvokeApiAsync("EasyParkLogin", JToken.FromObject(loginRequest));
JObject json = JObject.Parse(loginResult.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

try to check the return value of

```
await _service.InvokeApiAsync<LoginRequest, HttpResponseMessage>("EasyParkLogin", loginRequest);
```